# Refer to dictionary element by it's index number

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, indexing

I have some data array:

```
a = numpy.array([[  1,   2,   3,   4],
                 [ 10,  20,  30,  40],
                 [100, 200, 300, 400]])
```

And create `dictionary` using `a`:

```
d = dict(zip( ['a', 'b', 'c'], a))
```

So:

```
print(d)
{'a': array([1, 2, 3, 4]), 'b': array([10, 20, 30, 40]), 'c': array([100, 200, 300, 400])}
```

As I know in Python 3.x dictionary has constant order of elements. So, as I understand, if `a` was first element in `d` it always became first.

**My question, if my reasoning is right, is there any method to refer elements using it index number?**

I know I can't do
`d[0]` because there is no `0` key in it. But maybe there is some way: `d{0}` or `d.values[0]`.

Comment: Not constant ordering in Python 3 per se, but in *CPython* 3 in particular. The language spec has not changed in this regard (afaik).

Comment: Dicts are only ordered in python 3.6+, I think

Comment: if I am not mistaken, order was implemented in dictionaries from Python 3.6  upwards. That does not mean however that you can use indexes to refer to dictionary positions. But anyhow, if order is important to you, `dictionaries` are not the way to go.

Comment: Dictionaries still aren't *semantically* ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* access `list(d.values())[0]`, **but** you <s>may</s> will get a different value 
every time you execute the script (actually, every time the interpreter is restarted), so you really shouldn't do/rely on that.

```
λ python3                                                                                                                       
Python 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32                                  
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                                          
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}                                                                                                        
>>> list(d.values())[0] 
2                                                                                                                                                                                                           
>>> exit()                                                                                                                      

λ python3                                                                                                                       
Python 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32                                  
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                                          
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}                                                                                                        
>>> list(d.values())[0]                                                                                                         
1                                                                                                                               
>>> exit()
```

If you really want this behavior you can use an `OrderedDict`.

```
λ python3
Python 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
>>> list(d.values())[0]
1
>>> exit()

λ python3
Python 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
>>> list(d.values())[0]
1
>>> exit()
```

Comment: Thank you for this extended answer! It would be interesting to check `dict` order in Python 3.6, but anyway I will never use them this way. 
P.S. Do you know does `OrderedDict` have some disadvantages or limits (for example, they are slower than `dict`)? Or can I use them as `dict` without any additional precautions?

Answer (score 1):

The order maintained by dictionaries in Python 3 is an artifact of their implementation and **should not be relied upon** as it may change in the future.

There is no method for indexing a dictionary by it's position.